# Is it possible to focus the HTMLInputElement from the Chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I've created a chrome extension, which has a background and content scripts, from the background script I send the message to the content script, and then inside the onmessage callback I try to focus the HTMLInputElement like the following:

```
var element = document.querySelector('input[name="address"]');
element.focus();
```

But it doesn't work, I expect to see the cursor, but nothing happens, does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Is the tab currently shown and focused? Is there's another element matching this selector?

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot! I realized that despite the fact that the tab was shown it was probably not really focused because the popup window of my Extension was open, and because of that the cursor didn't appear in the input element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my Chrome Extension's Popup Window was open when the content script was trying to set the focus to the input element and this prevented the cursor from being visible.
Thanks, @wOxxOm for the tip.